# Improving quicksort by implementing insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

The running time of quick sort can be improved in practice by taking advantage of the fast running time of insertion sort when its input is nearly sorted.
When quicksort is called on a subarray with fewer than k elements, let it simply return without sorting the subarray. After the top level call to quicksort returns, run insertion sort on the entire array to finish the sorting process.

Argue that this sorting algorithm runs in O(nk + n log (n/k)) expected time. How should k be picked, both in theory and in practice?

Comment: This looks like a homework question, copied word-for-word. Please put more effort into your questions.

Comment: BTW, the question is nonsense. The running time of Quicksort cannot be improved by using a different algorithm. Nor can the taste of beer be improved by mixing beer with lemon soda. (Note: I am not saying that the taste of the resulting drink can't be better.)

Comment: What benefit will you gain if we do your homework for you? Why don't you do it yourself?

Comment: @ingo of course quick sort is really a family of algorithms.....

Comment: @Ingo: isn't that a bit like saying it's not possible to fix the bug in my function by changing the source of the function? Since then I'm not fixing the bug, I'm just replacing the buggy function with a non-buggy function. It's true, but pathologically pedantic because in practice when we say "fix a function" or "improve an algorithm", what we always mean is to replace it with a better one. When people say "quick sort", they rarely mean the exact quicksort algorithm first defined by Hoare.

Comment: @Steve, sure I agree as far as it concerns informal speech. But I feel in specifications, homework or interview questions (to name a few) the language must be accurate. In our case the question can be reduced to the last paragraph: "Assume we have an algorithm that runs in ..."

Comment: @Ingo: I'm actually a bit puzzled by the very last sentence too, "how should k be picked in theory". I don't think it *should* be picked in theory, pick it in practice! :-)

Comment: @Steve - so let's improve Quicksort by simply using Mergesort :-)

Comment: @Steve The reason behind the in theory bit will be to do with the fact that in big O notation, you normally ignore constants, and you would also ignore the linear part when part of the function is n(log(n)), because they become insignificant for sufficiently large n, however in practice, if k gets close to the same as n, you get close to n^2 efficiency, which is clearly worse than just doing quicksort

Comment: @Ingo: funny you should say that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091685/doesnt-qsort-c-library-function-work-on-linked-lists

Comment: @Tuskan360: oh I see, so in theory `k` should be asymptotically bigger than a constant, but less than `log n`, since otherwise you aren't improving the expected complexity. Presumably there's an optimum that minimises the big-O of `max(nk, n log (n/k))`. In practice, `k` should be whatever runs fast.

Comment: @Steve You're on the right track, but according to big-O notation, n log(n/k) always counts as bigger, since for sufficiently large n, it will be. This means that O(nk + n log(n/k))=O(n log (n/k)) regardless of what k is (provided k is a constant and not n). In practise you want to minimise (nk + n log(n/k)) which means the optimum value of k is the solution to the equation:
0=d(nk + n log(n/k))/dk

Comment: "provided k is a constant and not n" - I don't know that this is a reasonable restriction, I was assuming that `k` could be chosen differently on different runs. Further, I doubt that minimising `(nk + n log(n/k))` is right in practice, since there could be a huge disparity in the constant factors of each part of the algorithm (quicksort down to size k, then insertion sort).

Comment: True, I had failed to consider the constant factor in either algorithm.  The big-O notation remains as I said, but you would need to allow for some additional constant factor in practise

Answer (score 3):

Roughly speaking:

quicksort is `O(N log(N))`

By stopping when the sub-lists are of length k, the quicksort part becomes `O(N log(N/K))` because the depth you have to go to is reduced by a factor of K.

The insertion sort would normally be `O(n^2)` because you move each element at most n/2 times on average, and the factor of 1/2 is ignored.

Because the insertion sort is now on a fixed length array, you only move each element at most k places.  This results in the insertion sort part of your operation being `O(NK)`.

In theory, larger values of K give faster sorts, but that relies on the number of items being sorted being large.  In practise, the best value of k will depend on the value of n and can be found by differentiating the function in terms of k treating n as a constant.

This answer will probably need some fleshing out and formal proof if it is a homework question as Delan suggests.

Comment: There is potentially a horrendous problem.  If, for some reason, the Quicksort is not working correctly then the entire array will be sorted by the insertion sort.  Sl-o-o-o-o-o-w.

Comment: @rossum if quicksort is not working properly and you don't use this method then you have an unsorted list which is usually going to be worse.  I'm not advocating this as a way of dealing with a broken quicksort, but I don't see why you have any complaint with it.  Obviously the value of K must be carefully chosen or it could be very slow (small k becomes quicksort which is OK but not great, large k becomes insertion sort which is rubish)

Comment: It's true though that your test suite for the function should include some tests designed to check that the quicksort part isn't completely broken. In practice this means either you separate the two stages and test just the first one as well as the overall result, or else you keep it completely black-box and try to detect that time or number of comparisons appears proportional to n^2.