# Doesn't qsort() C library function work on linked lists?

Tags: c, linked-list, qsort

I am trying to sort a singly linked list which has been created and all its items,pointers initialized. I am trying to use qsort() C library function as shown below. It doesn't seem to sort the list. It is giving me compiler error saying: 
 **left of 'item' specifies undefined struct/union 'LINKED_LIST_S'** at line shown below in the code.

```
struct LINKED_LIST_S
{
         int item;
         struct LINKED_LIST_S * next; 
 } ;

typedef int (*cmpfn)(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2);

int mylistsort(my_list_t list, cmpfn f1)
{

    qsort ( list , 100, sizeof (struct LINKED_LIST_S), (fn) );
   return -1;
}


int sort_fn_ascend(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    int a = (*(LINKED_LIST_S *)ptr1).item; //Compiler error
   int b = (*(LINKED_LIST_S *)ptr2).item; //Compiler error

  return b - a;

}

int sort_fn_descend(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{   
   int a = ((struct LINKED_LIST_S *)ptr1)->item; //Compiler error
   int b = ((struct LINKED_LIST_S *)ptr2)->item; //Compiler error

  return a - b;

}
```

this is how the function mylistsort() is called at 2 places:

mylistsort(list, sort_fn_descend);//where list a properly initialized linked list pointer.

mylistsort(list, sort_fn_ascend);//where list a properly initialized linked list pointer.

1] Doesn't qsort() work on linked list if the head node poitner is passed as base array(first argument) to qsort.

2] How do I achieve the sorting of this linked list using qsort() in above code?

**EDIT: Thanks for the answers. Now I have implemented a way to sort a list as mentioned by @muksie approach 1] he suggested, as code below. Still qsort() does not return a sorted array of ints. 
First I want to sort an array of 100 elements, in descending order, but passed array is exact reverse, i.e. the elements are in ascending order of from 1,2,...100. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?**

```
int linkedListSort(LINKED_LIST_T list, newCompareFunction fn, void *usr_info)
{
    LINKED_LIST_T tmpptr = list;
    int newitems[N_ITEMS];
    int i=0;

    //Logic to get all the items in the list in a array
    while(tmpptr != NULL)
    {
        newitems[i] = tmpptr->item;
        tmpptr = tmpptr->next;
        i++;
    }
    tmpptr = list;
    i = 0;
    //Sort that array
    //qsort ( list , 100, sizeof (struct LINKED_LIST_S), (fn) );
    qsort ( newitems , 100, sizeof(list->item), (fn) );

    //store the sorted items back into the list.
    while(tmpptr != NULL)
    {
        tmpptr->item = newitems[i];
        tmpptr = tmpptr->next;
        i++;
    }

   return -1;
}

int sort_fn_descend(void *ptr1,void *ptr2)
{   
   int a = *((int*)(ptr1));
   int b = *((int*) (ptr2));

  return a - b;

}


int sort_fn_ascend(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    int a = *((int*)(ptr1));
   int b = *((int*) (ptr2));

  return b - a;

}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for giving pointers in your comments,replies. A bug fix in functions sort_fn_descen/ascent , and the code is sorting the lsit fine. FYI - the descent function above should return   b - a and ascend fn should return a - b

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I was able to solve the problem, using approach 2] suggested by @muskie in his answer, I am posting the answer here.
A bug fix in functions sort_fn_descend/ascend, mentioned in the edited OP was needed , and the code is sorting the list jsut fine. Bug fix FYI - the descend function above should return b - a and ascend fn should return a - b.

Answer (score 10):

`qsort` works on plain arrays of equally sized data, not linked lists.

Comment: Do you know what would be the behavior if i pass a linkedlist pointer to qsort instead of a array base pointer? And what is the compilation error fix?

Comment: You either get extremely weird results (where pointers are also considered data and also sorted in, or where unrelated data is sorted in) or perhaps an access violation error, or whatever. IOW, the behaviour is undefined. If there is no access violation, it will probably thrash your memory.

Answer (score 2):

To sort your linked list you can consider the following options:

1. Create a plain array with all values of the linked list, sort this, and transform back into a linked list.
2. Implement [the quicksort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) for your linked list data structure.

Comment: You probably don't really want to implement quicksort for linked lists -- if you were going to do that, implement a mergesort instead.

Comment: To point 2: won't be easy and certainly not very performant for a singly linked list. <g>

Comment: @goldenmean: there isn't one.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Sorry to understand clearly, are you saying there is no fix to remove the compiler error I mentioned or what is that you meant?

Comment: @goldenmean: there isn't a compilation error fix. `qsort` doesn't know how to follow the `next` pointer in your linked list. So there's no little tweak that will make what you want to happen, happen. You could replace `(LINKED_LIST_S *)` with `(struct LINKED_LIST_S *)` to shut that specific error up, but the code will still have undefined behavior.

Comment: @muksie and others: I have tried to implement your approach 1] above. Can u see the edited post and let know what could be wrong this time.